# Does someone know what versions of jquery mobile and jquery work together?

Tags: jquery

Does someone know what versions of jquery and jquery mobile work together?

It seems like jquery v1.64 works with jquery mobile vrc1. From a small amount of testing I've done.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a question about Drupal.

Comment: It is a little unclear what exactly the question is about.  If "jquery v1.64" really means "jQuery 1.6.4" and "jquery mobile vrc1" means "jQuery Mobile RC1" (http://jquerymobile.com/) then I would agree.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve multiple instances by running your version of jQuery in no-conflict mode. "No conflict" mode is the typical solution to get jQuery working on a page with other frameworks. It should allow you to use which ever versions of each you require.

[Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)